# c# wpf mvvm light как передать object sender в событии

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

есть devexpress grid control, в одной колонке которого comboBox. слушаю события SelectionChanged с помощью interaction и eventToCommand, но не знаю как получить сам comboBox (object sender), для определения строки, в которой данный comboBox, для получения их неё элемента, который биндится к этой строке. суть в том, что нужно отследить изменения в конкретной строке (получить guid, и новое значение, обновленное через comboBox). как получить object sender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xaml:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
     <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ComboChanged, Source={StaticSource vm}}" 
        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

viewModel:

```
public RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs> ComboChanged { get; set; }
public ViewModel() //ctor
{
    ComboChanged = new RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(HandleComboChanged);
}
private void HandleComboChanged (SelectionChangedEventArgs a)
{
    //(Combobox)a.Source
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В обработчике надо найти контейнер, и извлечь из него объект.
Примерно так делается для ListBox. Аналогично и для других контролов.

```
var lst = sender as ListBox;
var li = FindAnchestor<ListBoxItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
if (li == null) return;
var img = lst.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(li);
```

---

```
static T FindAnchestor<T>(DependencyObject current) where T : DependencyObject {
    do {
        if (current is T) return (T)current;
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    }
    while (current != null);
    return null;
}
```

Работающий пример - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/477112/3)